# Meaning of this notation, $\infty 1$ or ∞ (1 typeset in Blackboard Bold like  or $\Bbb I$)

Tags: notation

I'm reading a paper and I came across this notation, any idea?
I looked for this notation but couldn't find much anywhere, at first sight I thought it is L infinity norm, but it seems it isn't that as well.
$$
f(g)=\infty\Bbb{1}[{\Vert{w_g}\Vert}_0>K]
$$
Note that the '1' above was in this font:
$$
\Bbb{R}
$$
However, I couldn't make this font work for numbers using the guide here: 
[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

In case reference is required: 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04938.pdf

You can find this on the 4th page in this paper, 4 lines below equation (2).

Comment: Can you add the page number/location in the text where this is mentioned, so people don't have to skim read the whole paper

Comment: @lioness99a Wanted also to ask this but found: 4th line after the equation (2) on the page 4.

Comment: My bad, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Maybe the [blackboard $1$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set) is the [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Mean,_variance_and_covariance)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Given the context, it appears like that. However I'm unsure what the infinity symbol signifies.

Comment: I'm perplexed also... The formula has $\Omega(g)$ and I cannot find it in the text, also if $\Omega$ can mean the ["sample space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space). It seems that $g$ is a word and that $||w_g||_0$ is a convoluted way to mean the *lenght* of the word. Thus, the formula $1 [ ||w_g||_0 > K]$ returns 1 if word $g$ has lenght greater than K ?

Comment: Ok; page 3: $\Omega(g)$ is defined as the *complexity* of explanation $g$. Thus, the formula may mean: The complexity of $g$ is $\infty$ if $w_g$ has *lenght* > K.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And what is the value of the complexity if $\Vert\omega_g\Vert_0\le K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the statement $\Vert w_g\Vert_0>K$ is required to be false when we restrict to at most $K$ words in the bag, the most likely meaning is that $1[p]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) of a proposition $p$, normally denoted $[p]$, and the factor of $\infty$ changes the bracket from $0$ or $1$ to a [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) of $0$ or $\infty$.